# Comparing wrapper object of generic type to with everything that is comparable to inner type?

Tags: scala, generics, wrapper, equals-operator

I am trying to build a wrapper around data saved in a redis database.
What I want to do is access it as normal as possible as if I have a scala value of some type.
It works, except for comparing it to anything (with `==` or similar).
**So I want to be able to compare it to objects of the inner type.**

Best I'll give example code first. This is a rough abstraction of my wrapper:

```
case class RedisObjectValue[T](name: String, default: T) {
  def :=(value: T): Boolean = {
    redisMagic.set(name, value)
  }

  def get: T = {
    redisMagic.get[T](name).getOrElse(default)
  }

  override def equals(o: Any) = o match {
    case ov: RedisObjectValue[T] =>
      if (this.hashCode() == ov.hashCode()) true // Same reference
      else this.get == ov.get
    case v =>
      // If we don't compare to another RedisObjectValue, let the equals method of data type handle it
      this.get.equals(v)
  }
}
```

I have an implicit conversion set up in the companion object so that I can use the wrapper wherever I would use the base type.

```
object RedisObjectValue {
  implicit def objectValueToValue[T](ov: RedisObjectValue[T]): T = {
    ov.get
  }
}
```

So, as I said, everything works.
Except the comparing stuff. For that, let's say I have a class `Player` two values, `userId` and `name`.

```
class Player {
  val userId = RedisObjectValue("userId", 0)
  val name = RedisObjectValue("player", "Unknown")
}
```

And now I have a list of players and want to filter to get all players with name "Unknown".

```
list.filter(_.name == "Unknown")
```

Which does not work. If I extend the filter filter call and write a function, it tells me in IntelliJ "Comparing unrelated types".
And yeah, I understand what it is telling me, but I want to solve that. I mean I can easily compare Long to Int and similar stuff, so there must be a way to make them comparable, right?

In the code above I have even written the equals function which uses the comparison to the inner type, but it seems like it is not used.

Of course, I can always call `.get` on the values, like `players.filter(_.name.get == "Unknown")`, but that's a bit dirty and I would love to avoid that.

## EDIT: Found the real problem after some analysis

Old text still above for reading, I will explain the problem here now.
I have a snippet which shows what is not working: https://ideone.com/AmQrkH

The Problem: The `RedisObjectValue` is defined as `Long`. When I am comparing it now with

```
players.filter(_.userId == 2)
```

for example, it doesn't give any results, even if there are players with `userId` 2, or to be more exact: `2l`.

For direct `Long` it's not a problem.

```
players.filter(_._id == 2)
```

is working.
So is there any fix for that, so that comparable instances of classes to `T` can also be compared to `RedisObjectValue[T]`, and not just `T` itself?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "it does not work"? It looks like what you have should  work. Show a complete (minimal) code snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I explained the error IntelliJ tells me. And "it does not work means that no element in the list matches the criteria, even if there are some where it should. The problem seems to be that the compiler sees a comparison between an instance of `RedisObjectValue[T]` and an instance of type `T`, which does not match in types, so are generally not comparable. I'll try to code a working snippet.

Comment: This works for me: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b659523c8a5897f64d4b So, there must be some nuance in the code you have not shown, that introduces the problem. That's why I was asking for a complete code snippet to reproduce.

Comment: @Dima: Thank you for your help already. Found my "error" now. Got even a snippet working. See here: https://ideone.com/AmQrkH  The problem is that the type is Long, but I am comparing to Int. for every other class with a normal Long value it works to just write an Int to compare with, but not in this example. Know any fix for that, so that comparable classes to `T` can also be compared to `RedisObjectValue[T]`, and not just `T` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this.get.equals(v)` with `get == v`. (Removing `this` is unrelated, just a good idea in general, the main thing is to use `==` instead of `equals`).

Consider this:

```
 scala> 2 equals 2L
 res79: Boolean = false

 scala> 2 == 2L
 res80: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Okay, this seems to be the answer here. It works for me now. Which is quite confusing, I thought `.==` just calls `.equals` internally, cause what I needed to make my object comparable was implementing the equals function?

Comment: Yeah ... I am actually not sure exactly what the explanation is. It _does_ in fact just call `.equals`, but there is some additional magic going on with boxing and unboxing primitive types.